# Zip file from URL not valid

Tags: c#, webclient, dotnetzip

I followed another post to be able to zip the content of an URL..

When I click my button Download, I "zip" the content of the URL and I save it in the default download folder...

So far this is my code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient(); 

ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile();

string filename = "myfile.zip";

zipFile.Password = item.Password;

Stream s = wc.OpenRead(myUrl); 

zipFile.AddeEntry(filename, s);

return File(s, "application/zip", filename);
```

it´s similar to this one (which zips the content of a folder... ) (It works correctly)

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile();

zipFile.Password = item.Password;

zipFile.AddDirectory(sourcePath, "");

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
zipFile.Save(stream);
zipFile.Dispose();
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

return File(stream, "application/zip", fileName);
```

So, I want to do exactly the same with an URL..

THanks!

Comment: I think you're misunderstsnding what a zip file can store. A zip file is a collection of files in a compressed state within a wrapper. You can't simply compress some text. You need to write your text (the URL) to a file (.txt for example) -> get your server script to zip the txt file up -> serve up the zip file as a download.

Comment: I don't understand this code. You're creating a `ZipFile` object, and adding an entry to it, then you dispose it? Where did the zip file go? And why are you returning a file around the `s` variable? I think that what you're getting from the server, if anything at all, is just the contents of the `myUrl` file, named as a zip file, but not actually being a zip file.

Comment: The file is going to the default Download folder.. in my case "Downloads". You are right, the file is not a real zip file, only named it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at the end I use this code and It works like I wanted...

Thanks to all again!

```
 string fileName = "filename" + ".zip";

 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

 ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile();     

 WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(myUrl);

 webRequest.Timeout = 1000;

 WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
 {
     string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
     zipFile.AddEntry("myfile.txt", content);
 }

 zipFile.Save(stream);
 zipFile.Dispose();
 stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

 return File(stream, "application/zip", fileName);
```

Comment: Creating a new Streamreader from `GetResponseStream()` and using `ReadToEnd()` fixed my issue! (I didn't need to set a timeout on my request)

Answer (score 0):

The example you provide will create an entry inside your zip file with the contents from the stream but you are doing nothing to save and return the actual zip file. You need to use the creation code from your second example.

```
// name of zip file
string filename = "myfile.zip";
// filename of content
string contentName = "mypage.html";
WebClient wc = new WebClient(); 
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile();

zipFile.Password = item.Password;
Stream s = wc.OpenRead(myUrl); 
zipFile.AddeEntry(contentName, s);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
zipFile.Save(stream);
zipFile.Dispose(); // could use using instead
s.Dispose(); // could use using instead....
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
return File(stream, "application/zip", fileName);
```

this will return a zip file with one file in it called content.html containing the contents of the url stream

Comment: the problem is when I save the stream (zipFile.Save(stream))...
hmm... it´s really strange because it should work... at least download something...

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with the Stream s... 
because once I try to save it in the zipFile I get this execption:
"It is not possible to use PKZIP encryption on a non-seekable input stream"...

Comment: @minoyo In that case your best bet is to copy the source stream either into a temporary file or in to a memory stream fist.