# Sitecore: Download all files on a page as a zipped file

Tags: c#, download, zip, sitecore

I have links to several files on a page.

The user can either click on the download button for each file or then click on download all. If he click on download all, all the files on that page must be downloaded as a zipped file.
The files are in the media library and their url is, for e.g:
url = "/~/media/file.ashx"

If I want to download it individually, it works

```
Response.Redirect(url);
```

If I write this code to zip the files,

```
FileUtil.ZipFiles("/myzip.zip", new[]{url})
```

it throws the following exception:
Could not find part of the path "c:\~\media\file.ashx"
I'm guessing this exception is thrown because it expects the file to exist on the file system.

I would like to bundle all the files in a zip file and then download the zipped file. I do not want to have to add the zipped file to the media zibrary.
Is this even possible?

Comment: You might have to do a web request to get the content of the files and then put that into a zip file. There's an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380134/zip-file-from-url-not-valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to create a new httpRequestBegin pipeline to look for your custom URL and not resolve it against Sitecore item resolver. In that pipeline you can make it do what you like. It is similar to what you do with a 301 redirect.

https://laubplusco.net/url-mappings-in-sitecore-done-easy/

http://insitecore.tumblr.com/post/37848690556/thoughts-on-httprequestbegin-custom-item-lookups

Here is the code. Credit to the above post.

```
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest;

namespace InSitecore.Sample {
    public class CustomItemResolver : HttpRequestProcessor {

        public override void Process( HttpRequestArgs args ) {
            if( Context.Item == null ) {
                return;
            }

            // Implement custom custom item lookup logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the config patch.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <httpRequestBegin>
        <processor type="InSitecore.Sample,InSitecore.Sample"
          patch:before=
"processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </httpRequestBegin>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be overkill but you could use the `GetMediaStream()` method of a Sitecore media item then add each stream to a zip file. something like this:

```
      using (ZipOutputStream zipStream = new  ZipOutputStream(File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\App_Data\" + outputFileLocation)))
      {
            zipStream.SetLevel(9); 

            foreach (var mediaItem in mediaItems)
            {
                    var memStream = mediaItem.GetMediaStream();
                    Contract.Assume(memStream != null);

                    ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(mediaItem.Name + "." + mediaItem.Extension);

                    zipStream.PutNextEntry(newEntry);
                    StreamUtils.Copy(memStream, zipStream, new byte[4096]);
                    zipStream.CloseEntry();
            }

            zipStream.Finish();
            zipStream.Close();
        }
```

This is using the `ICSharpCode` 3rd party library to create zip files.

You can then convert that to a byte array and do something like this to enforce the download - for MVC this is in a Controller rendering returning a `FileResult`. You can do a RedirectToAction to this action on a controller

```
        string contentType;
        ContentDisposition cd;

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        return File(filedata, contentType);
```

You could also use a pipeline processor to call the above code. The processor would have to check for a certain pattern in the requesting URL e.g /Myzip and return the response. Example here of using a processor to return a response

http://sitecorejunkie.com/2016/01/24/yet-another-httprequestbegin-pipeline-processor-to-handle-page-not-found-404-status-code/

Comment: I think his issue is that he is calling a url that does not exist. Your code is very helpful, but only after he resolves the url to be able to use it.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. The URL does not exist until the handler resolves it.